# Sharepoint Framework webpart import images and fonts

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I use Angular 4 in the Sharepoint framework but I want to add several fonts and images to my web part. Does someone have experience with this and give me a hand or point me in the right direction? When packaging my solution it does not take the assets into account.

Thanks!